# I just create .net core pwa app i try calling in another apk file in pwa app but some not working

Tags: .net-core, progressive-web-apps

I just create .net core pwa app i  try calling in another apk file in pwa app but some not working.

i have use intent calling in

i used multiple code  below share:

Ex:-
Capture 1


Capture 2


OPEN WHATSAPP ANDROID


OPEN FaceRD ANDROID


OPEN SBM


OPEN SBM 2